# How to use basic authentication to create oAuth2 token for github api?

Tags: iphone, ios, oauth, github, github-api

I am working on an iPhone app in which I am using `github api`.

To access github I am using Oauth with `web application` flow. Means First It opens login screen then I give username & password.

But now I want to use `OAuth` with password grant type. It means I want to access directly with providing username & password in request URL, (No separate login screen).

How its possible? Can anybody help me ?

Comment: OAuth is meant to prevent you from ever needing to deal with a user's actual credentials yourself. That's a good thing. Even if you mean well, there's nothing stopping you from posting someone's credentials to your web server, changing their password, etc. OAuth puts the control over managing access back in the user's hands (except with Netflix, whose OAuth implementation sucks because users have no ability to revoke permanent keys issued to individual apps -- a feature they _removed_). The web application flow is the right thing to do. You should have OAuth tokens, not user credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I know that web application flow is the right thing, but I want non-web application flow. To get Oauth tokens, it requires username & password. So how will I get token without giving username & password?

Comment: Assuming it's an app you plan to release in the App Store, I'd still maintain that it's a very bad security practice and that you'd be generating far more than "a small number of tokens". That said, here's [a gist caspyin made](https://gist.github.com/2288960) that provides some examples using curl.

Answer (score -1):

As described on github developer documentation for [Non-Web Application Flow](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#non-web-application-flow) you will need to create a new authorization.

Example:

```
curl https://api.github.com/authorizations \
--user "put_username_here" \
--data '{"scopes":["user"], "client_id":"your_client_id", "client_secret":"your_client_secret}'
```

This will prompt you for github password and return oAuth token as a response.

For information on how to do HTTP basic authentication on iPhone, check [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html).